# jQuery need fix the code

Tags: jquery

I need a help ... i wanna add in this code effect like slide up / slide down.
i already add this effect but only the problem what i found if i wanna close the box is 
box stay open

sorry for my english ;)

thanks for any help..

```
$(function() {
    $(".avatar1, .social").hide();
    $(".teamBox").click(function() {
        $(this).find(".avatar1, .social").slideDown('slow')
            .end().parent().siblings().find(".avatar1, .social").slideUp('slow');
    });
});
```

**DEMO** [here](http://jsfiddle.net/K3A98/embedded/result/)

Comment: What does your HTML look like?

Comment: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/K3A98/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
$(function() {
    $(".avatar1, .social").hide();
    $(".teamBox").click(function() {
        var $el = $(this).find(".avatar1, .social"); // cache elements to be toggled
        $el.slideToggle('slow'); // only slide toggle current clicked
        $(".avatar1, .social").not($el).slideUp('slow'); // slide up all others
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9Ek6n/

Answer (score 5):

You can toggle function to do this :

```
$('.teamBox').click(function() {
     $(this).find('.avatar1, .social').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

See demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Trufa/K3A98/2/).

Comment: I took the liberty to add a demo.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
$('.teamBox').click(function () {
    $('.avatar1, .social').slideUp('slow');
    $(this).find('.avatar1, .social').slideDown('slow');
});
```